# Cannot dereference void; trying to use builder pattern

Tags: java, builder

EDIT: I was returning void when I should have been returning `ArrProcBuilder`. I'm kind of glad this happened as I don't understand. Why do you need to return `this` in methods belonging to the builder class? Since the methods are mutating the object and the last call to `.build()` returns the target object with those parameters, why is it needed to return anything before hand?

So in `new builder.x().y().z().build();` are actually 4 different objects created: one for x, one for y, and one for z and build?

I'm trying to use the builder pattern but something doesn't seem right. The program compiles with

```
    ArrProcBuilder apBuild = new ArrProcBuilder(randData);
    apBuild.addSwapSelection((byte)swap);
    apBuild.addPivSelection((byte)pivot);
```

but with this I get an "void cannot be derefernced" error.

```
    ArrProcBuilder apBuild = new ArrProcBuilder(randData);
    apBuild.addSwapSelection((byte)swap).addPivSelection((byte)pivot);
```

Here is addSwapSelection

```
public void addSwapSelection(byte swapSelection)
{
    this.swapSelection = swapSelection;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the return type of `addSwapSelection`? You should show the relevant part of the code.

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include the source code of ArrProcBuilder

Comment: In your first example, you are running the `addPivSelection` method on `apBuild`.  In your second example, what object do you think you are invoking it on?

Answer (score 1):

addSwapSelection() doesn't return `this` like it should.

Answer (score 1):

If the method *addSwapFunction()* returns a reference to the object, i.e. its code would look something like

```
public ArrProcBuilder addSwapSelection(byte b) {
    //some code

    //returns a reference to this object
    return this;
}
```

then you can chain calls to *addSwapFunction()* as you did.  I suspect its return type is void, which means you won't be able to make chainable calls.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing is what happens when an object  is evaluated, so "cannot be dereferenced" probably means you're using a variable as an object when it isn't.

here the `addSwapFunction()` returns a reference to the object.